# How mock scala val filed?

Tags: java, spring, scala, unit-testing

I have scala class like that:

```
@Component
class SomeClassForTest {
  @Autowired
  implicit val type: Type = null
...
}
```

With pure spring this code work fine. But whe I trying create test with Mockito:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class SomeClassForTest {

  @InjectMocks
  var SomeClassForTest : instance = null

  @Spy
  val type: Type = new Type()

  ...

    //in before method
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}
```

Injecting mock does not work until I write `var` instead of `val` in class for test:

```
  @Autowired
  implicit var type: Type = null
```

Is it possible to inject `val` in test classes?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so, val means value. It defines during definition. but Autowired stuff is using Reflection to set field with new Value, so it is deferred. Underscore _ means that it initialises the variable to a default value based on the Type.